# In VTK, what is the easiest way to lerp between two vtkUnstructuredGrid or two vtkPointData?

Tags: c++, interpolation, vtk

I have multiple timesteps of `vtkUnstructuredGrid`. They have same number of point data arrays, and only differ in point data values.

If I have a lerp ratio *t* and I want to create a lerped `vtkUnstructuredGrid` between two time steps, is there a way easier than manually calculating every single value one by one?

Comment: TIL lerping is an "_Abbreviation of linear interpolation_". Thanks, wiktionary!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a simpler way. I often need to create vtk datasets that are differences between two sets (timesteps). Until now I haven't found an alternative to doing this manually.